# IE 11 issue - Alert() popup is getting displayed after minimizing the current window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have the following simple html page with a text field which  displays alert message on blur event. Whenever user focuses on the text field and click anywhere within the window , then alert message is getting displayed after minimizing the current window i.e the back end of the alert message doesn't display the current window as it is minimized. Only when ok button of alert message is clicked , the window is displayed back. This issue is not happening while using tab button in text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<input name="txtFromDate" tabindex="6" id="txtFromDate" style="width: 75px;"  onblur="alert('Clicked');" type="text" maxlength="10" value="04/11/2017">

</body>
</html>
```

Versions of IE11 that has this issue – 11.0.9600.16384(windows server 2012 R2) ,  11.0.9600.18378(windows server 2012 R2)  ,11.0.9600.18618(Windows 8) 
Versions of IE11 that is not having this issue - 11.0.960.18617(installed in windows 7)
Kindly suggest if there is any fix for this.

**Note** : This is working fine in IE8

Comment: you should validate your form fields in the form.submit(event) handler or onchange, oninput, onkeypress, onkeydown AND in the onbeforeunload event of document. Your sample code does not show the logic and process flow of what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like you want to prompt the user to save their form data if they close the tab/window or navigate away from the form.

Comment: This is just a sample code which is replication of actual application. What we are trying to achieve is to validate and display alert message if wrong date is entered through onblur event(i.e if user move away their focus from text field). The issue is : alert message is displayed but not within the same window, it displays behind the current window by minimizing it.

Answer (score 3):

onblur="(this!=document.activeElement)&&setTimeout(function(){alert('Clicked')},0)"